# Appending string while iterating it

Tags: javascript

I have an object in which every key has array of string corresponding to it 
I want to replace the \n with `<br>`

```js
var i = 0;
var obj = {
  'one': ['hello\nworld', 'java\nscript'],
  'two': ['hi\nworld', 'java\nscript\nis\nawesome']
}



for (let key in obj) {
  let reg = new RegExp('\n', "g");
  for (var i = 0; i <= obj[key].length; i++) {
    document.body.innerHTML += obj[key][i].replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
  }

}
```

Comment: i want to replace \n with <br>

Comment: `i <=` is always wrong. Should be `<`

Answer (score 1):

you could take the `Object.values` of the object, `flat` the resulting array, `map` it to replace the `\n` with `<br />` , then `join` the final array and append it to the document :

```js
const data = {
  'one': ['hello\nworld', 'java\nscript'],
  'two': ['hi\nworld', 'java\nscript\nis\nawesome']
};

const html = Object.values(data).flat().map(e => e.replace('\n', '<br />')).join(' ');

document.body.innerHTML += html;
```

Comment: what if after each list element i want to put <br> tag for example hello<br>world<br>java<br>script<br>

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here `for(var i=0 ; i<=obj[key].length; i++)`. You are using `i<=obj[key].length`. Here `i` will greater than the length of the `array` and it will throw error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property `replace` of `undefined`

You should use `i < obj[key].length`.

A better way to do that is converting array to string by using `join()`

```js
let obj = {'one' : ['hello\nworld','java\nscript'],
 'two' : ['hi\nworld', 'java\nscript\nis\nawesome']}

for(let key in obj){
  let reg = new RegExp('\n',"g");
  document.body.innerHTML +=  obj[key].join('\n').replace(reg,'<br>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix the typo `<=` which should be `<`

Alternatively have one replace:

```js
var obj = {
  'one': ['hello\nworld', 'java\nscript'],
  'two': ['hi\nworld', 'java\nscript\nis\nawesome']
}

obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj).replace(/\\n/g,"<br/>"))

for (let key in obj) {
  for (var i = 0; i < obj[key].length; i++) {
    document.body.innerHTML += obj[key][i];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function

```
function reemplazar(str, nval, find){
    var nstr="";
    var cadena= new RegExp(find, "g");
    var ind = (str.match(cadena) || []).length;
    for(var h=0; h<ind; h++){
        if(h>0){
            nstr = nstr.replace(find, nval);
        }else{
            nstr = str.replace(find, nval);
        }
    }
    return (nstr==="") ? str : nstr;
}
```

here you send into `str` param the string you wanna process, `nval` param is the new value to all occurences and the `find` param is the char or the string you wanna search into `str`